# How to use SELECTEDVALUE for filter date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I had an issue with Power bi date slicer.
I need solve when select date slicer
date value in axis visualization will be same value in slicer and +7 day

example i select date is 5/05/2021
output is date value in axis is 5/12/2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table in your slicer is related to your fact table you won't need SELECTEDVALUE.
Assuming it is marked as date table.

```
My Measure +5 days = CALCULATE([My measure], DATEADD(Date[Date],1,day)
```

If not and you have autodatetime on.

```
My Measure +5 days = CALCULATE([My measure], DATEADD(Date[Date].[Date],1,day)
```

With SELECTEDVALUE if it is a parameter table.

```
My Measure +5 days = 
    VAR _selecteddate = SELECTEDVALUE(Date[Date])+5
RETURN
    CALCULATE([My measure],'myTable'[Date] = _selecteddate)
```